# Drupal 8 Page Cache

Tags: 8, caching, tokens

I am using dynamic tokens in page title, which is always being cached. I want to stop that.

I have try by disabling page cache using

```
function hook_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  \Drupal::service("page_cache_kill_switch")->trigger();
}
```

But they didn't help me, Is there a way so i can only disable or refresh page title cache of a specific page.

My title looks like " lorem ipsum [mydynamictoken:subtoken]  "

Answer (score 1):

This code works, but you need to place it in the title block.

I wouldn't use the page cache kill switch though, uninstall the module *Internal Page Cache* instead and then the dynamic page cache can still cache pages where  uncacheable blocks are placeholdered.

Answer (score -1):

Disable cache for a custom page from route declaration.
If you want to disable cache for a custom controller (Custom module), You have no_cache option (YOUR_MODULE.routing.yml).
Example :
File : mymodule.routing.yml

```
mymodule.myroute:
  path: '/mymodule/mypage'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\Pages::mypage'
    _title: 'No cache page'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
  options:
    no_cache: 'TRUE'
```